# After an express function is complete, how to get all the affected database (MongoDB) records?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Let's say I need to add a custom user log to my API. When a function completes successfully, I need to record all the affected mongo records. One function can modify multiple records.

Is there a way to do this without calling a function to record these modifications every single time we do the modification inside the function?

Comment: Which function? MongoDB methods such as `update()` already return the number of affected records in the response. You really need to show what you are actually doing and what you expect to see in response.

Comment: @NeilLunn Then I have to add a function to store the updates on every `update()` call. I need to globally catch all the changes. I haven't start recording or tried because I don't know how to even start.

Comment: You're being asked to show some "code" representative of what you think you are trying to do. If you don't have the code yet, then pseudocode. Or really more important, show some sample documents and describe said action affecting those documents, and then state what you expect to see as "affected" in result. That makes your question a lot clearer than it presently is. So please add some detail using the  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49867923/edit) link on your question.

Comment: I think the plugin `mongoose-patch-history` solves my issue. Trying it out now...